# Delete de una entidad en DB con spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Buenas tardes,tengo un sistema de información con una DB en Mysql. La conexión con ella y el mapeo lo realizó con Spring.

Estoy creando los servicios y tengo una duda muy importante.
Pongo en contexto, tengo dos Entidades Ranger y Currículum, con una relación bidireccional 1:1. Cuando borro una instancia de Currículum en la DB, compruebo que efectivamente esa instancia deja de existir, sin embargo el atributo currículum de Ranger no se ha puesto a null, sino que sigue teniendo el currículum previamente borrado. ¿No debería hacerlo spring por si solo? ¿Tengo que hacer manualmente un ranger.setCurriculum=null?

Dejo el código del delete:

```
public void delete(final Curriculum curriculum) {
    Ranger principal;
    Curriculum result;
    Assert.isTrue(curriculum.getId() != 0);
    principal = this.rangerService.findByPrincipal();
    Assert.notNull(principal);
    result = this.findCurriculumByPrincipal();
    Assert.notNull(result);
    Assert.isTrue(curriculum.equals(result));
    this.curriculumRepository.delete(curriculum);
    principal.setCV(null);
}
```

El findCurriculumByPrincipal saca de la DB el curriculum del Ranger logueado.
Sé que quizás no es información suficiente pero es una duda conceptual, quiero saber si spring borra las FK de Ranger al borrar el Curriculum

Tengo hecho un test con JUnit para el delete que da acierto cuando en el método delete pongo el principal.setCV()=null;

```
@Test
public void testDeleteCurriculumOfPrincipal() {
    Curriculum result;
    super.authenticate("ranger1");
    result = this.curriculumService.findCurriculumByPrincipal();
    Assert.notNull(result);
    this.curriculumService.delete(result);
    result = this.curriculumService.findCurriculumByPrincipal();
    Assert.isNull(result);
    super.unauthenticate();

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías quitar el código del test que es un poco redundante y añadir el código de las dos entidades para ver como las tienes relacionadas? porque no deberías poder borrar un registro si está siendo utilizado como FK en otra tabla, eso debería resultar en una excepción de hibernate o de base de datos lo que me hace pensar que las entidades las tengas mal relacionadas.

Answer (score 0):

Primero asegúrate de que no haces un Rollback en tus test, de manera que lo que ejecutes se vea reflejado en BBDD.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ClassCofigurationInCaseIsNeeded.class)
@Transactional
@Rollback(false) ->> Para ver cambios en BBDD "No hagas rollback despues del test"
public class TestCustomName {...}
```

Por otro lado tienes que tener un mapeo JPA correcto en tus entidades, por ejemplo para una relación bidireccional 1:1  -> B tiene una FK a A:

```
public class A{ 
    @Id
    @Column(name="A_ID")
    private Long id; 

    // Asegúrate de que el NO-Propietario de la FK (A) tiene CascadeType.ALL
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
    private B b; 

    ...
}
public class B{  
    @Id
    @Column(name="B_ID")
    private Long id;  

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", referencedColumnName = "A_ID")
    private Lead lead; 

    ...
}
```

Insertando correctamente tu cascade all (no tiene que ser all puede ser exclusivo solo a eliminaciones) deberias de obtener el valor de null que esperas en BBDD. Espero que esto te ayude con tu problema.
Un saludo.